# Distance metrics in Scikit Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, distance, euclidean-distance

I was looking at some of the [distance metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.distance_metrics.html) implemented for pairwise distances in Scikit Learn. They include

> ‘cityblock’
>
> ‘euclidean’
>
> ‘l1’
>
> ‘l2’
>
> ‘manhattan’

Now I always assumed (based e.g. on [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)) that euclidean was the same as  L2; and manhattan = L1 = cityblock.

Is this not true in Scikit Learn? Otherwise, why have the same thing under different names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.distance_metrics.html) tells you exactly what's going on. Each of these strings are mapped to one internal function.

```
metric  Function
‘cityblock’ metrics.pairwise.manhattan_distances
‘cosine’    metrics.pairwise.cosine_distances
‘euclidean’ metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances
‘l1’    metrics.pairwise.manhattan_distances
‘l2’    metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances
‘manhattan’ metrics.pairwise.manhattan_distances
```

So your assumptions are correct, as `cityblock`, `manhattan` and `l1` are all mapped to `pairwise.manhattan_distances` internally!

Why are there multiple names in use? *Because different people from different backgrounds use different names for the same ideas.*

I do think it's better that i can use `cityblock` if the name rings a bell (for me) instead of needing to make the connection by myself that `cityblock == l1` if `cityblock` is not supported explicitly.